# How to connect a Python gRPC stub to a Go gRPC server in the same process

Tags: python, go, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-go

I have a Python app that loads Go code through a shared library. I want to call a gRPC server in
the Go part from the Python part of the application. I could make the Go server listen on a
TCP socket, but I want to avoid the overhead of TCP, want to avoid the use of sockets (as I will be creating and destroying many of these at a very high rate, possibly in parallel) and want to communicate entirely in-memory.

I was hoping I could stub a net.Connection, and simply communicate reading/writing data across the
languages using simple functions. The Go end doesn’t seem to be a problem, as you can stub a net.Listener for communication.
If this were Go on both ends, I could use
[bufconn](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/test/bufconn) to connect the client to
the server directly, and communicate through an in-memory buffer.  But for Python, the lowest level to stub for a gRPC client I can find is a
Channel, for which there seems to be a [testing Channel](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_testing.html),
but this level seems to be much to high to stub conveniently.

Are there other ways to connect gRPC between Python and Go, without having to stub every RPC call in the API on the language boundary?

Comment: Communication over TCP on the loopback interface _is_ entirely in memory. The overhead is more then likely minuscule. That being said, connecting via a unix socket can be an alternative that doesn't use the TCP stack.